# Creating an sqlalchemy hybrid_property that allows for "in_" operator

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

How would you make a [`hybrid_property`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) that allows the `in_` clause? What would the SQLAlchemy [`expression`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#defining-expression-behavior-distinct-from-attribute-behavior) look like?

```
class Version(Base):
    version_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    package_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('package.package_id')
    version = Column(String(32), index=True)

    @hybrid_property
    def pkg_id_concat_vers(self):
        # "23~~0.2.4"
        return "{}~~{}".format(self.package_id, self.version)

# TODO
#@pkg_id_concat_vers(self):
#    pass

# Using the naive `(not) in` doesn't actually apply the filter
data = ['23~~0.2.4', '57~~0.0.1']
result = (session.query(Version)
          .filter(Version.pkg_id_concat_vers in data)
          ).all()

# Using `in_()` throws an Attribute Error, as it's a string.
data = ['23~~0.2.4', '57~~0.0.1']
result = (session.query(Version)
          .filter(Version.pkg_id_concat_vers.in_(data))
          ).all()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLAlchemy supports the `+` operator on expressions with type `String`, so you can cast your columns to `String` and then do something like this:

```
@pkg_id_concat_vers.expression
def pkg_id_concat_vers(cls):
    return cast(cls.package_id, String) + "~~" + cast(cls.version, String)
```

Comment: Hot damn! That's perfect, thanks! FYI for future people: `from sqlalchemy import cast`